# Possible to analyse SQL queries in Sonar?

Tags: sql, sonarqube

I am using Sonar to analyse our Java code in a very large project. We mostly use Hibernate, but there are also a lot of plain SQL queries in our code. Is it possible to analyse those SQL queries by Sonar? I noticed there is a plugin for at least something similar, but I am unsure whether it fits my needs here. Some of our queries cause headaches, so it would be convenient if Sonar could notify of SQL anti-patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a commercial [PL/SQL plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/plsql/), but its designed to analyse Oracle files.

Not aware of any Sonar tool which analyzes SQL strings, embedded within Java programs.

Answer (score 0):

A commercial TSQL option is http://www.techcognia.com/Home.aspx

Don't know of any free/open source version for Microsoft SQL.