# how to Check if sonar rule set includes checks on DAO layer query

Tags: java, sonarqube

how to Check if sonar rule set includes checks on **DAO layer query** 
Like: correct primary key being used in data fetch ,two tables merging etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to analyse SQL queries in Sonar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533744/possible-to-analyse-sql-queries-in-sonar)

Comment: Just adding a little bit: After going through your answer  :           what's the difference between SonarTSQL and SonarPLSQL I mean which can be best used or we have two plugins as an option

Comment: T-SQL is Microsoft SQL Server stored procedure syntax, and PL/SQL is Oracle stored procedure syntax.